# Pipe to the clipboard in command line, with no root privilege to install

Tags: non-root-user, clipboard

Normally I use `xclip` to pipe results into the clipboard. However, on a cluster I am accessing I don't have the required root privileges to install it. (I tried copying over files but then got into trouble with a missing dependent `/lib64/libc.so.6`).

Is there any simple way to pipe into the clipboard without this library? Can it be done in a simple Bash script?

Comment: Your question may also be a how do I install programs without privileges to install them. For this you need to build them to be statically linked, or linked against libraries in the same directory tree (e.g. `~/usr/...` in stead of `/usr/...`

Comment: @ctrl-alt-delor, I agree the answer might well be that that is the simplest solution in which case I a link to such an answer would be the answer (and this could be considered a duplicate). But this also seems like quite a simple functionality so perhaps there is another solution with for example a bash script that achieves this without the `/lib64/libc.so.6` library.

Comment: How do you access the cluster? I believe clipboards only exist in X11 sessions, and remote access usually don't involve X.

Comment: @Quasímodo, I use ssh (possibly with the -X argument).